# Firefox mousemove bugs out if left mouse button pressed on svg image

Tags: firefox, svg, mouseevent

So in this little example I have a square (thumbnail) following the mouse around, in the final product it will be the place where the dragged item will be visible. I ran into a problem however that if I try to drag and drop a svg `<image>` in **Firefox** it bugs out and doesn't follow the mouse anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7besrw/

Same applies if you have different mouseEvents, they all bug out and stop working until you unpress left mouse button and move again. I've tried `e.preventDefault` `e.stopPropagation` and `return false` to prevent weird behaviour but without luck.

Any help would be **GREATLY** appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
$(document).on('dragstart', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=511188